# nested ifs to calculate stock price

Tags: google-sheets, nested-if

I do trade on several stock exchanges (Belgium, USA and Canada).
I'd like to use a nested if in my Google spreadsheet to calculate transaction costs. It will be calculate based on this table:

[transaction costs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UpmJ.png)

For example: if I buy for €4500 shares on Euronext Brussels the transaction costs will be €9.75.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are too many options/variables for a nested IF but there is a formula that can return the correct value.

```
=index(C4:F6,match(B10,B4:B6,0),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C3:F3>C10,0),0))
```

[image]

It's a bit scary so let's break it down

```
=index(C4:F6
```

this part looks at the full range of prices and then uses 2 **match** functions to find the row and column in that range where the correct price is.

```
 =index(C4:F6,match(B10,B4:B6,0)
```

The 1st match function returns the row number from the stock exchange list B4:B6 that matches the value in B10

```
=index(C4:F6,match(B10,B4:B6,0),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C3:F3>C10,0),0))
```

The 2nd match looks for the first value in range C3:F3 (2500,5000,25000....) that is greater than the value in cell C10.

Here's a link to my file. It will prompt you to create your own copy.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BsPy99nCXql592JRQNyQcKuYZduZ5RCChm5uwDxFOz4/copy?usp=sharing